# Memory leak in sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup.notifyPrinterChange

Tags: java, tomcat, printing

When I stop my Tomcat server in windows sometimes I have to wait long time, in these cases I got this warning:

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Stack trace of thread:
 sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup.notifyPrinterChange
 sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup.access$100(Unknown Source)
 sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup$PrinterChangeListener.run(Unknown Source)
```

The only printer-connected code in my web app is a reader of available printers with:

```
PrintService[] printServices = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
```

Do you know how to avoid this problem?

Comment: What jvm\os version do you use?

Comment: Win10, but I have the same problem with Win7. JVM 32bit 8.0.1310.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That thread is [started by `Win32PrintServiceLookup` itself](https://github.com/dmlloyd/openjdk/blob/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/src/windows/classes/sun/print/Win32PrintServiceLookup.java#L94-L102), *unless it thinks you are on Windows 98*, which it verifies by using system property `os.name`, so here is a funky (tentative) workaround:

```java
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
if (osName.startsWith("Windows")) { // or SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS if you use commons-lang
    System.setProperty("os.name", "Windows 98");  // Pretend you're on Win98
}
PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
System.setProperty("os.name", osName); // Restore original value
```

I have not tested (no Windows system around today), so I just hope it still gets the list once. It also means you lose the ability to register changes of printers during the application lifetime.

Comment: Surely not a solution, but nice idea. I'm testing it and for now it is ok.

Comment: Wow yeah I was not expecting to get that answer accepted or get the bounty, it's just an ugly workaround that I wanted to share, mostly for its funky side... I also expect this to fail in later Java versions if/when they change `Win32PrintServiceLookup`. But I'm glad it helps now :)

Comment: For now it is the only/best solution :-)

Comment: A little update: it is better to wrap everything with `if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS){...}` otherwise in linux enviroment it tries to apply the windows methods and tomcat crashes...